ILRepack & Post Build Event
We have a C# library solution that is using ILRepack to combine related assemblies into a single DLL.  Since we also want the resulting DLL to be deployed to the GAC, we added the following to the Post Build Event in Visual Studio:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8
Tools\gacutil.exe" -u $(TargetName)
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\gacutil.exe"
-i $(TargetFileName)

Unfortuntately, when we build our solution, the pre-merged DLL is being deployed to the GAC instead of the merged DLL.
Given this, it looks like the following order of events is occuring:

Visual Studio Build
Post Build Event runs (our post build logic runs and moves the pre-merged DLL to the GAC)
ILRepack is merging the Assemblies into the DLL

Therefore, by the time ILRepack has run in step 3, the "pre-merged" DLL has already been deployed to the GAC.
Is there a way to ensure that the merged DLL is being deployed to the GAC?

Try this:
gacutil /l assemblyname | findstr /i /C:assemblyname


You can manually deploy the merged DLL to the GAC using the following command line:
gacutil -i Merged.dll

